# Open Knowledge Articles in Console Tab from Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, tab, console

I am trying to open a knowledge article in a console tab from a flow.

Clicking the hyperlink in the flow from display text is rendering the article in the same page as the flow.

Attempts were made to change the _target in the hyperlink to open the flow to no success.

Using the finishLocation parameter on the flow is not an option as knowledge article needs to be accessed during the flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a Lightning component in the flow screen and pass the Knowledge Article details (knowledgeArticleId, title) from Flow to the Lightning component.

In the Lightning component, just display the Knowledge Article as a hyperlink.

```
<a><lightning:button variant="base" label="{!v.title}" onclick="{!c.openKnowledgeArticle }"/></a>
```

and in the controller, use `e.force:navigateToSObject` with `slideDevName` as `related`.

This will open the Knowledge Article in a related console tab.

```
   openKnowledgeArticle : function(component, event, helper) {
    $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject" ).setParams( {
        "recordId": component.get("v.knowledgeArticleId"),
        "slideDevName": "related"
    } ).fire();
}
```